# knowing ontology concepts from owl files

Tags: java, semantic-web, ontology

I have downloaded a load of owl files. I want to know what are the concepts defined in these files and then want to annotate other text based off these concepts. How would this be done? Code in Java would be good. I am a beginner. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either [OWL API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net), mainly for parsing OWL, or [Apache Jena](https://jena.apache.org), mainly for RDF. Depending on what you want to do, they have great tutorials with sample code. If you have any specific question after you have read these, post a detailed question with the error message.